# How do you access all users home directory?

Tags: linux

How do you access all users directory not just my own

Via root

Comment: By being `root`

Comment: Add more clarification. Why and what do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

First, you enable root by entering `su -`. If you want to see directories and view file names, just do `cd /home/insert username here/`, then `ls`, and then from there, navigate the directories like you would if you were using that user. If you wanted to see contents of, and/or write to files, and/or execute them, Follow the steps for seeing inside the directories, then for the file(s) you want to see, then `chown filename`, and `chmod u+rwx filename`. Make sure to undo it when you are done, by `chmod u-wrx filename`, and `chown insert username here /home/enter username here`

Comment: By saying **insert username here**, I mean the user which you want to see the files from!

Answer (score 0):

user root is privileged to access any directory on the filesystem:

to find someone's home directory location:

```
grep <username> /etc/passwd|awk -F':' '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

to list directory contents of this directory:

```
ls <user home dir>
```